# When sending notification to multiple users is the user object accessible within notification?

Tags: laravel, notifications

Using this to send a notifiation to all users in Collection:

```
Notification::send($users, new NewProjectAlert($project));
```

Now within my notification class NewProjectAlert am I able to access the individual $user object?
eg:

```
$this->user->first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't acces $this->user but you can access $notifiable so in you notification class depened in which channel you use you can use it as the following

```
**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Hey ,' . $notifiable->first_name )
                ->line('...');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that "first_name" property, is that predefined? ie It does not contain all fields of the $user object used.

Comment: you are welcome, No it's not predefined you can access the User (Notifiable) Object's Properties so you can call $notifiable->first_name OR $notifiable->email based on your user model, so you can imagine $notifiable as $user.
Let me know if it does the trick.